# Adding multiple .length calls together

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I'm using the Learn to Program book, which teaches newbies how to program starting on Ruby. The guy says to try to create a program that asks me my individual names (first middle and last), then uses `length` to add together and get the sum of how many characters are in my name. I got this far without screwing up:

```
puts 'enter your first name'
first = gets.chomp
puts 'first name is ' + first + '.'
puts 'enter your middle name.'
middle = gets.chomp
puts 'middle name is ' + middle + '.'
puts 'enter your last name.'
last = gets.chomp
puts 'last name is ' + last + '.'
puts 'Full name is ' + first + ' ' + middle + ' ' + last + '.'
```

So I tried a few things such as

```
puts 'there are ' + first.length + middle.length + last.length.to_s + 'characters in your name!'
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: `(first.length + middle.length + last.length).to_s`

Comment: For some reason ruby wants nothing to do with the parenthases. It keeps popping up with an arrow pointing at them as if to say "what is this supposed to be?"

Answer (score 2):

Try using a double quoted string and let ruby evaluate the code for you with the #{} notation

```
puts "there are #{first.length + middle.length + last.length} characters in your name!"
```

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

It's simple really. In ruby single quoted strings are treated as just text regardless of what you put in them whereas double quoted strings are parsed by the Ruby interpreter. So if you use a double quoted string with the #{} notation then everything inside the curly braces will be treated as ruby code.

To make your original way work then try adding the values together and assigning them to another variable then outputting that variable

e.g.

```
total_length = first.length + middle.length + last.length
puts 'there are ' + total_length.to_s + ' characters in your name!"
```

The problem with your approach was that you were adding the three values together but the 3 value had a to_s on it so ruby would be confused as to whether the last number was supposd to be a string or a number and the previous two additions were not strings therefore should not be included in a the puts statement.

hope that makes sense

Comment: Well, the code actually tried to work with that change, but instead of giving me a length it just popped up blank instead of where the sum of the numbers should have been. Oh well, I've actually emailed the author to ask him to clarify. I really don't know why he didn't go over this in his book for beginners...

Comment: on second thought jamesw, that did work! thank you! Unfortunately, the way you wrote that out... I haven't seen anything like that in his book yet, so it's a bit more advanced than what i'm supposed to be doing... I guess. Idk, I actually have yet to find a programming book that is geared towards someone who knows literally nothing at all about programming. For some reason all these authors seem to think people are born knowing this stuff. But uh.. thanks again :D

Comment: @JohnnyBoy I have updated my answer in the hope that it clarifies your query ad what you were doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

```
puts 'there are ' + (first.length + middle.length + last.length).to_s + 'characters in your name!'
```

You were converting the last.length to a string and then trying to add it to an integer, which won't work.  The brackets tell Ruby to do the math, and then convert the result to a string.